# Merge two Outlook.com accounts (using aliases) without disrupting email?

Tags: outlook.com, alias

Is such a thing possible?

As in, if you have two accounts `A@outlook.com` and `B@outlook.com`, and you want to close account `A` and make `A` an alias for account `B`, then is it possible to do this without making emails sent to `A` undeliverable for some period of time?